# How to read a tag of 20 INT arrays to see if it equals a value in Studio 5000 Logix Designer ladder logic for Compact Logix

Tags: arrays, search, compare, plc

I have a customer sending me unassigned integer fault codes through Modbus TCP. I am reading those registers and using message instructions to bring them into my CompactLogix PLC.

The codes can be populated into any position in a 20 element integer array. How do I search the array for a fault code?

For example
If Fault[0] or Fault [1] or Fault [2]......or Fault [20] == 2005 energize OTE Engine_coolant_low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the File Search and Compare (FSC) instruction. The FSC instruction compares values in an array, element by element.

Operation stops either when the .POS value equals or exceeds the .LEN value or when the expression evaluates to true. If the search is successful the "Found" bit (.FD) is set and .POS indicates where it was found.

Here's an example for your use case.

[image]

Comment: I have an array of 20 for Fault_Code that I want to reads 50 different faults in the 20 arrays in Fault_Code. How do Fault_Search.POS read 20 array of Fault_Code?

Comment: The FSC instruction is essentially a `for` loop. In the example, when `Search_Trigger` is true the FSC evaluates the expression with `.POS` equal to zero. If the expression is false, FSC increments `.POS` and evaluates the expression again. This continues until the expression is true or it reaches the end of your array.